# How to cut a thick glass block at home?

Tags: materials, manufacturing-engineering, glass

Due to pandemic, there are a lot of machine shops closed and delays in getting something custom made. I was wondering how to cut a triangular glass prism (~5cm hypotenuse) in the middle so I have two half slices? I was originally thinking of ordering some glass cutters that can cut up to 20 mm thick glass, but I'm pretty sure I won't be able to cut it into smaller pieces with just that. Are there any home made conventional ways of cutter thicker than normal glass? Or is there any specific tool I can order to cut thicker glass?

Comment: Note that glass dust is relatively hazardous to breathe in, so if you are using a sawing method, it should be continuously flooded with water to prevent the dust from becoming airborne.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way, used to drill holes through the plate glass wall of an aquarium.

Imagine a thick brass shim. we cut slots along one edge so that it looks like a saw blade with oddly square teeth.

We set this "blade" reciprocating against the glass piece we wish to cut in half and smear the "teeth" with diamond polishing paste, which loads the kerf cuts along its "cutting" edge.

The back-and-forth action embeds diamond particles into the surface of the soft brass shim, transforming it into an abrasive machining tool. it begins very slowly sawing through the prism.

We replentish the diamond paste from time to time so as to keep the cutting edge "fresh" until the brass shim has abraded its way all the way down through the prism.

If needed, we use a trickle of water as saw lube during this process.

Comment: +1 for this answer. A similar method is used for drilling holes in glass of almost any thickness. A brass (sometimes copper) tube is used with the teeth created in the described manner. With a modeling clay dam around the work area, an abrasive powder can be added to water to improve the cutting action.